# how to write all Soap Request available in Project using Soap UI Groovy

Tags: groovy, automated-tests, soapui

I have a soap project with 4 Test Suite,each Test Suite has some Test Case and each Test case has some test steps[Soap Request,Groovy Script] 
    I am able to access all the properties using mentioned code below , HOWEVER,code is writing blank request/response file in local system **

```
def Project = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project;
for(def i=0;i<Project.testSuiteCount;i++)
{
log.info Project.getTestSuiteAt(i).name 
def Suite = Project.getTestSuiteAt(i)
  for(def j=0;j<Suite.testCaseCount;j++)
  {  
   log.info Suite.getTestCaseAt(j).name
   def TCase = Suite.getTestCaseAt(j)
    for(def k=0;k < TCase.testStepCount;k++)
    {
    def TStep= TCase.getTestStepAt(k)
    def req =  context.expand('${'+TStep.name+'#Request}')
    new File("D:/Directory/"+Suite.name+"_"+TCase.name+"_"+TStep.name+"_"+k+".txt").write( req )
    }
  }
}
```

** plz help to solve this, **

Comment: Please, align the code properly

Comment: @ Andrii Abramov Done

Comment: @albciff  could you help here ,

Comment: @Rao could you help

Comment: What is your use case? Is it that you already run the test suites and just wanted to save the request and responses?

Comment: I am trying to place this script in a independent disabled test suite .. which should write files once I am done with my execution..

Comment: Please check the solution and see if that is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there are multiple approaches to achieve this.
Below is the one of the approach.

Here is `Groovy Script` which writes the requests and responses.

This script assumes that user has already run the test suites so that responses are available to be saved.

Create a new *test suite -> test case ->* add *Groovy Script* test step and copy the below script into it.

**Groovy Script**:

```groovy
/**
* This groovy script saves the request and response
* And this script will be able to write the responses
* into files if and only if there is response available
**/
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep

//Change direcoty path if required
def directoryToSave = 'D:/directory'

//Not required to change the script beyond this point

//date time is appended to the file name
def dt = new Date().format('yyyyMMdd_HHmmss')

//Closure to save the file
def saveToFile(file, content) {
    if (!file.parentFile.exists()) {
         file.parentFile.mkdirs()
         log.info "Directory did not exist, created"
    }
    if (content) {
        log.info "Writing the content into file :${file.name}"
    file.write(content) 
    assert file.exists(), "${file.name} not created"
    } else {
        log.warn "the content is empty, not writing the content into file"
    }
}

//Get the project object
def project = context.testCase.testSuite.project

//Loop thru the project and save the request and responses
project.testSuiteList.each { suite ->
    suite.testCaseList.each { kase ->
                kase.testStepList.each { step ->
            if (step instanceof WsdlTestRequestStep) {
                def reqFilePath = new File("${directoryToSave}/${suite.name}_${kase.name}_${step.name}_request${dt}.xml")   
                def resFilePath = new File("${directoryToSave}/${suite.name}_${kase.name}_${step.name}_response${dt}.xml")  
                saveToFile(reqFilePath, step.testRequest.requestContent)
                saveToFile(resFilePath, step.testRequest.responseContent)
saveToFile(step)
            } else {
                log.info "Ignoring as the step type is not Soap request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick response , but I am able to write only one req/res using this ..Error groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script2.saveToFile() is applicable for argument types: (com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep) values: [com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep@ba0d09] Possible solutions: saveToFile(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) error at line: 35

Comment: like it is mentioned, there should be responses available or tests must be run before running the above script. If one request can be written, then there shouldn't be any problem for others too.

Comment: Let me try again, but what if there is read timed out in response

Comment: Just ignores with a `warn` message in the log.

Comment: What is your pre-condition? what do you mean by working for first step only? it works only for soap request step. Are you able follow the script?